# Ember.js : Custom file structure & file naming

Tags: ember.js

I want to use the following file structure ***and*** file naming:

```
/app
  /components
    /some-component
      component.some-component.template.hbs
      component.some-component.class.js
  /routes
    /some-route
      route.some-route.handler.js
      route.some-route.template.hbs
      route.some-route.controller.js
  /models
   model.some-model.js
```

It's *kind of* similar to the `pods` structure but it's not exactly it since the file naming is totally different.

Any hints on how I can achieve this? I tried overriding Resolver methods as it's been suggested [here](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/serving-all-routes-from-a-specific-folder-using-pods/8581/9) but this is only for when you use `pods` and you simply want to group all of you route-folders in one parent-folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest NOT adopting your own resolver, but instead encourage waiting for the module unification work to be completed (https://emberjs.com/statusboard)

Straying from the community adopted best-practices here is a good way to run into snags down the road. I spent some time helping a client shift away from their own custom resolver who had gone down this path and wouldn't suggest doing so